# An integral related to Hilbert transform

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm taking a course on basic quantum field theory (a physics course). I met such an integral during the
course: compute $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\rho(x)}{x-x_{0}} d x$, where $\rho$ is a REAL function with some good properties (smooth of course, and you can add any needed analytic conditions to it). This type of integrals are very common in the quantum theory, and the professor told us that this was the so called Hilbert transform and indeed we have the following formulas:

Let $f$ be an analytic function, then:
$$
\begin{array}{l}
\operatorname{Re}\left[f\left(x_{0}\right)\right]=\pm \frac{1}{\pi} P \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\operatorname{Im}[f(x)]}{x-x_{0}} d x ,\\
\operatorname{Im}\left[f\left(x_{0}\right)\right]=\mp \frac{1}{\pi} P \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\operatorname{Re}[f(x)]}{x-x_{0}} d x.
\end{array}
$$
where $P$ means integration in the sense of the principal value. (This can be obtained via the residue theorem.) (A standard reference: Hassani's Mathematical physics, a modern introduction to its foundations, second edition, 2013)

But I don't know how to realize $\rho$ as $\operatorname{Im}[f(x)]$ or $\operatorname{Re}[f(x)]$ on the real axis. I think in general this can't be done: not all $\rho$ can be realized as something like this. So is there any theorems related to "when a smooth $\rho$ on $\mathbb{R}$ can be realized as $\operatorname{Im}[f(x)]$ or $\operatorname{Re}[f(x)]$?

Comment: It's possible if $\rho$ can be harmonically (meaning that $\Delta\rho=0$) extended to the plane. The real and imaginary parts of analytic functions are always harmonic, and every harmonic function is the real or imaginary part of some analytic function.

Comment: Oh, thanks!@Vercassivelaunos